# How to parse a CSV file, update a field, then save

Tags: ruby, csv

I need to read a CSV file, update a field, then save the changes. I have everything working fine except saving my changes to the field I'm updating:

```
require 'csv'
@parsed_file = CSV::Reader.parse(File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/doc/some.csv"))
@parsed_file.each_with_index  do |row, x|
  address = row[5]
  l = Location.address_find(address)
  if l != nil
    puts "#{l.name} at #{l.address}"
    row[14] = l.store_code
    puts row[14]
  else
    puts "No matching address Found!!!"
  end
  #What do I do here? Something like this? CSV::Writer.generate(@parsed_file) 
end
```

What do I do here? How do I save the changes I made and update the file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What I would do is write the updated records to a new file and then, if you want, after you have finished your program can delete the old file and rename the new file to have the original file name.

To do this I would open the output file at the top of your code, outside the `each_with_index` loop. e.g.

```
csv_out = CSV::Writer.generate(File.open('new.csv', 'wb'))
```

Then inside your `each_with_index` loop you can write the current row to the new file like this:

```
csv_out << row
```

Then at the end you can close the new file:

```
csv_out.close
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, `CSV::Writer` is no longer in the standard library. An equivalent version of the code using the newer `CSV.foreach` (for reading) and `CSV.open` (for writing) is:

```
CSV.open("path/to/updated_file.csv", "wb") do |csv_out|
  CSV.foreach("#{RAILS_ROOT}/doc/some.csv") do |row|
    address = row[5]
    l = Location.address_find(address)
    if l != nil
      puts "#{l.name} at #{l.address}"
      row[14] = l.store_code
      puts row[14]
    else
      puts "No matching address Found!!!"
    end
    csv_out << row 
  end
end
```

Comment: would I csv_out.close outside the loop?

Comment: Yep, the `csv_out.close` would be outside the `each_with_index` loop as you only want to do this once and after you have finished looping over the rows from the original file.

Comment: Use the block form of `open` because it's smarter and idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: CSV::Writer isn't available on ruby 1.9+?

Comment: CSV::Writer has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @brauliobo

Comment: Thanks @RajSharma - have added a version that uses the newer CSV library to the end of answer.